# By ID: Marking if I have an oberservation of the next / previous date

Tags: r

I have a data set that looks likes this:

| ID | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 20/11/2004 |
| 1 | 27/11/2004 |
| 1 | 28/11/2004 |
| 1 | 29/11/2004 |
| 2 | 30/11/2004 |
| 2 | 05/08/2005 |
| 2 | 06/08/2005 |
| 3 | 07/09/2004 |
| 3 | 12/10/2004 |

What I would like to do is to add "Treatment" column according to the following law. For each row, if for *the same ID* there is an observation one day after then mark 1. If there is an observation one day before mark 2. If for a certain row and given its ID there is an observation both one day before and one after then mark 3 (Thus if a row is marked 1, the next row will always be marked 1 or 2). Else, mark 0.

So, In this example I would want to get:

| ID | Date | Treatment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20/11/2004 | 0 |
| 1 | 27/11/2004 | 1 |
| 1 | 28/11/2004 | 3 |
| 1 | 29/11/2004 | 2 |
| 2 | 30/11/2004 | 0 |
| 2 | 05/08/2005 | 1 |
| 2 | 06/08/2005 | 2 |
| 3 | 07/09/2004 | 0 |
| 3 | 12/10/2004 | 0 |

How should I go about it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

We'll need to convert your `Date` column to `Date` class, and then this is pretty easy with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
your_data %>%
  mutate(Date = mdy(Date)) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Treatment = case_when(
      (Date - 1) %in% Date & (Date + 1) %in% Date ~ 3,
      (Date + 1) %in% Date ~ 1,
      (Date - 1) %in% Date ~ 2, 
      TRUE ~ 0
    )
  )
```

Comment: If I may ask a follow-up question. I am using the code Gregor has generousally shared. However, now I need to mark another situation, where a date shows up twice (or more) that is, I have to observations on the same date. How could I tweak the code to mark these cases as well? Thank a lot